# Eliminar duplicados... bajo ciertas directrices

Tags: sql-server, sql

Tengo una tabla `Peticiones` cuyo diseño es:

```
NPeticion       - nvarchar
FechaApertura   - date
TipoPeticion    - nvarchar
FechaResolucion - nvarchar
...
(más campos, irrelevantes para este asunto)
```

La cuestión es que intento hacer una query que elimine duplicados de registros que tengan igual `NPeticion`, `FechaApertura` y `TipoPeticion`  quedadome con el registro con  `FechaResolucion` más reciente y distinta de `'NULL'` a menos que todos los registros sean `'NULL'` que me quedaria con cualquiera de ellos .

Hice esta query: (posiblemente no lo más elegante/eficiente pero es lo que se me ocurrió)

```
;with aBorrar as
(select [NPeticion], [FechaApertura], [TipoPeticion],[FechaResolucion],
    row_number() over(partition by [NPeticion], [FechaApertura] 
                      order by  [FechaResolucion] desc) rn
  from [dbo].[Peticiones]
  where NPeticion in (

          SELECT
            [NPeticion]
        FROM
            [dbo].[Peticiones]
        GROUP BY
            [NPeticion],FechaApertura, TipoPeticion
        HAVING 
            COUNT(*) > 1

            )
  and [FechaResolucion] <> 'NULL'
  Union 
  select [NPeticion], [FechaApertura], [TipoPeticion],[FechaResolucion],2
  from [dbo].[Peticiones]
  where NPeticion in (

          SELECT
            [NPeticion]
        FROM
            [dbo].[Peticiones]
        GROUP BY
            [NPeticion],FechaApertura, TipoPeticion
        HAVING 
            COUNT(*) > 1                
            )
  and [FechaResolucion] = 'NULL'
)
select * 
from aBorrar 
where rn > 1;
```

**Explicacion:**

Como `FechaResolucion` es un `nvarchar`, si ordeno `desc` para quedarme con la más reciente, aparece primero los valores `'NULL'`. Por eso hago un select ordenando los registros que no son `'NULL'` y luego union de aquellos null.

Pero eso no resuelve el problema de si todos los duplicados contienen esa columna igual a `'NULL'` me los borraria todos...

**¿Cómo hago que me deje un registro en el caso de que todos los duplicados tengan `FechaResolucion = 'NULL'`?**

**Ejemplo de datos:**

```
[NPeticion]       [FechaApertura] [TipoPeticion] [FechaResolucion]
'20171204000001'     12/04/2017        'A'          '12/04/2017'
'20171204000001'     12/04/2017        'A'          '10/04/2017'
'20171204000001'     12/04/2017        'A'          '10/04/2017'
'20171204000001'     12/04/2017        'A'             'NULL'
'20171204000002'     12/04/2017        'B'             'NULL'
'20171204000002'     12/04/2017        'B'             'NULL'
```

**Resultado actual** (registros que se borrarian):

```
[NPeticion]       [FechaApertura] [TipoPeticion] [FechaResolucion]
'20171204000001'     12/04/2017        'A'          '10/04/2017'
'20171204000001'     12/04/2017        'A'          '10/04/2017'
'20171204000001'     12/04/2017        'A'             'NULL'
'20171204000002'     12/04/2017        'B'             'NULL'
'20171204000002'     12/04/2017        'B'             'NULL'
```

**Resultado esperado** (registros que se borrarian):

```
[NPeticion]       [FechaApertura] [TipoPeticion] [FechaResolucion]
'20171204000001'     12/04/2017        'A'          '10/04/2017'
'20171204000001'     12/04/2017        'A'          '10/04/2017'
'20171204000001'     12/04/2017        'A'             'NULL'
'20171204000002'     12/04/2017        'B'             'NULL'
```

<sub>Nota: Yo no he diseñado la BD. Modificar su diseño no es posible.</sub>

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Algunos comentarios sobre tu código actual. Uno de tus problemas es que al simplemente hacer `ORDER BY FechaResolucion DESC`, y siendo `FechaResolucion` un string con el formato de fecha `dd/mm/aaaa`, no va a ordenar correctamente, sino que en forma alfabética.

Por otro lado, no es necesario separar dos consultas para ver si contienen o no `NULL`, sino que se puede hacer algo como lo siguiente:

```
WITH CTE1 AS
(
    SELECT  NPeticion,
            FechaApertura,
            TipoPeticion,
            NULLIF(FechaResolucion,'NULL') FechaResolucion
    FROM dbo.Peticiones
), CTE2 AS
(
    SELECT  *,
            RN = ROW_NUMBER() OVER( PARTITION BY NPeticion, FechaApertura, TipoPeticion
                                    ORDER BY CONVERT(DATETIME,FechaResolucion,103) DESC)
    FROM CTE1
)
SELECT *
FROM CTE2
WHERE RN > 1;
```

En este caso, la primera CTE ni siquiera es necesaria hacerla por separado, y podrías usar la segunda reemplazando `CONVERT(DATETIME,FechaResolucion,103)` por `CONVERT(DATETIME,NULLIF(FechaResolucion,'NULL'),103)`, pero prefiero dejarlo así porque lo encuentro más legible.

Comment: Este es el tipo de respuestas que da gusto leer en SQL

Answer (score 1):

Yo simplemente ordenaria por `FechaResolucion DESC` con un `ROW_NUMBER()` en un subconsulta, para despues filtrar por solo `Number = 1` y te traera la fecha mas reciente o cualquiera de los Nulos en caso de que todos sean nulos

```
;WITH _peticiones AS(
SELECT ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY NPeticion ORDER BY CAST(P.FechaResolucion AS DATE) DESC) [Number],
    P.NPeticion, P.FechaApertura, P.TipoPeticion, CAST(P.FechaResolucion AS DATE) [FechaResolucion]
  FROM @Peticiones P 
) SELECT * FROM _peticiones P WHERE P.Number = 1
```

Comment: El problema es que el op tiene valores como string `'NULL'`, no son `NULL`s